# Вывести текущую дату

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Вопрос наверное глупый и многим покажется несерьезным, но я вынужден его задать, т.к. сам решения не нашел.

Нужно вывести в TextView дату в таком виде: Число.Месяй.Год (пример: 27.04.2017).
Важный нюанс: работать должно на API 19 и выше.

Answer (score 4):

Можно, например, сделать таким способом:

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date());
```

Comment: Тоже работает, но с API 25 и выше, а на с API 19 и выше.

Comment: @Evgeny, вы не правы. Класс доступен с API 1. Переходим по ссылке: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html и в правом верхнем углу указана версия API с которой он доступен

Comment: Самый простой и удобный вариант. Спасибо!

Comment: @Evgeny, если вас устраивает ответ, отметьте его как принятый, нажав на галочку.

Answer (score 3):

Все просто

```
DateFormat dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(SimpleDateFormat.SHORT);
String text = dateFormat.format(dateValue);
```

Форматирование даты будет в соответствии с настройками локали пользователя.

Comment: Но это будет работать только на API 24 и выше. А мне необходимо начиная с API 19 и выше

Comment: Надо импортировать java.text.SimpleDateFormat и java.text.DateFormat. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39055963/simpledateformat-gives-api-error

Comment: А что это даст?

Comment: Эти классы добавлены с API 1

Comment: Andrroid Studio просто удаляет их (при помощи автоимпорта), т.к. они не используются ей. Поэтому проблема не решилась

Comment: @Evgeny если существует более одного класса с одинаковым именем, но из разных пакетов, то AS не добавляет любой по своему желанию, а предлагает выбрать из имеющихся. Вам нужно выбрать из пакета `java.text`. Вообще, ответ правильный и никто вам другого не напишет, то что вы не можете справится с автоимпортом, как бы ваша проблема. Отключите его вообще и делайте импорт вручную тогда.

Comment: Да вы правы - это моя проблема. Но так категорично об этом говорить не обязательно. Я решаю как могу и если бы все знал, то и вопросов не возникало. А так увы, я вынужден обращаться за советом и угадать кто и как их воспримет не могу. Спасибо за решение.

Comment: @Evgeny, все верно. Просто надо уметь разделять проблемы и решать каждую отдельно, а не валить все в кучу.